# HoverIntent Config, Not Picking Up

Tags: jquery, hoverintent

I've used hoverIntent before but it doesn't seem to be working on this site, here is the config:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.hoverintent/1.9.0/jquery.hoverIntent.js"></script>
```

```js
var config = {
  sensitivity: 1000000000000000,
  interval: 1000000000000000,
  timeout: 1000000000000000
};

jQuery('.left-menu-items li').hoverIntent(function() {
  jQuery(this).find('.sub-sub-menu-items').first().css({
    'display': 'block'
  });
}, function() {
  jQuery(this).find('.sub-sub-menu-items').first().css({
    'display': 'none'
  });
}, config);
```

Am I missing something? It doesn't seem to listen to the config. I'm using jQuery 1.11.3

Comment: `hoverIntent()` isn't a standard jQuery method. You need to include the library in your page to enable it's functionality. Have you done that? Also note that jQuery 1.11.3 is a little out of date. You should be using 1.12.4 at least. Ideally, 3.3.1

Comment: Yes, It's included at the top... I'll edit the post.

Comment: In which case check the console for errors

Comment: Nothing at all in the console.

Comment: Last idea, check the output of this in one of the handlers: `console.log(jQuery(this).find('.sub-sub-menu-items').length)`

Comment: Console returns 1

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to fix this, it looks like the above code will only work with an older version of hoverIntent, looks like R5 version.

This code below, works with the current version of hoverIntent:

```
jQuery(".left-menu-items li").hoverIntent({
    over: function () {
        jQuery(this).find('.sub-sub-menu-items').first().show()
    },
    out: function () {
        jQuery(this).find('.sub-sub-menu-items').first().hide()
    },
    timeout: 700,
    sensitivity: 10
});
```

Comment: Thanks - this helped me actually get my function to work (minus the jQuery() as I used $() as it was inside jQuery anyways)